# Limit the text width of TextView (Not the background image)

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView with a background that declared as:

```
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/questionText"
android:layout_width="250dp" 
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="26px"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:background="@drawable/blue"
/>
```

the problem is that the background image is like a frame, so i want the
text inside to have a margin from the background image dimensions.
Is this possible?

10X alot,
have a gr8 weekend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want sounds like padding.

```
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/questionText"
android:layout_width="250dp" 
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="26px"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:background="@drawable/blue"
android:padding="5dp"
/>
```

This would put a 5 pixel border around the actual text showing the background through.

Incidentally, layout_margin is also a parameter and is used to put space between the entire view, background included, and other views.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to make 9-patch drawable. It defines where the text can be without specifying padding in the control.